# Using the Google Chrome Sandbox

Tags: c++, google-chrome, sandbox

There are several resources out there that explain how the sandbox in Chrome works and what it does to protect users from malicious code.

[Chromium Blog](http://blog.chromium.org/2008/10/new-approach-to-browser-security-google.html)
[Chromium Developer Documentation](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/sandbox)
[Sandbox FAQ](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/sandbox/Sandbox-FAQ)

That's great, and I like the OS-centric design that they have in place (somewhat of a "The OS probably knows how to secure itself better than we do, so we let it" approach.) They also mention in several places that the sandbox itself was designed to not be dependent on Chrome but instead more-or-less standalone so that theoretically any process could be sandboxed as long as the architecture of the program is compatible (sandboxed code must run as it's own process as a child of a non-sandboxed parent.)

I just happen to have an application who's design makes it ripe for sandboxing, and was able to get a parent/child process working with it. I've got the Chromium code and... have no idea what to do next.

Has anyone out there actually sandboxed anything with this yet? Are there any resources that document it's usage or APIs? I would imagine it should be pretty simple, but I'm at a loss for where to start.

EDIT: My finding below in the answers!

Comment: Just FYI: I have finally gotten a sandbox running (after LOTS of experimentation), and after I work out a kink or two I'll post my findings here.

Comment: Sorry, still working on it. The last thing I want to do is post something misleading or broken. I'm still planning on posting it, though. Thanks for the interest!

Comment: I just noticed that this question has been closed as "not constructive", which puzzles me quite a bit. The question was not "Should I sandbox" or "What are the merits of sandboxing" but a very specific "How do you utilize the sandbox code". Furthermore, it had a very specific answer which doesn't leave much room for debate and provides a valuable resource for other users looking for the same thing. Frankly if this isn't a model example of a constructive question I'm really not sure what is!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Okay, so here's what I found about sandboxing code with Chrome.

First off, you'll need to go [get the chromium source code](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-windows). This is *big*, and will take a while to get, but I've yet to find any reliable shortcuts to checkout that still yeild usable results. Alos, it's very important that you follow the instructions on that page VERY CLOSELY. The Google crew knows what they're doing, and aren't keen on useless steps. Everything on that page is necessary. Yes. Everything.

Now, once you get the source, you don't actually have to build chrome in it's entirety (which can take hours!) to use the sandbox. Instead they've been nice enough to give you a separate sandbox solution (found in the sandbox folder) that can build standalone. Build this project and make sure everything compiles. If it does, great! If it doesn't, you didn't follow the steps on the build page, did you? Hang your head in shame and go actually do it this time. Don't worry, I'll wait...

Now that everything has built your main point of interest is the sandbox_poc project ("poc" = Proof of Concept). This project is basically a minimal GUI wrapper around a sandbox that will launch an arbitrary dll at a given entry point in a sandboxed environment. It shows all the required steps for creating and using a sandbox, and is about the best reference you've got. Refer to it often!

As you look through the code you'll probably notice that the code it actually sandboxes is itself. This is very common with all the sandbox examples, and [according to this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/chromium-dev/browse_thread/thread/f6ee308557249e81/e9c1114575b15033) (which may be outdated) is possibly the only working way to sandbox at the moment. The thread describes how one would theoretically sandbox a separate process, but I haven't tried it. Just to be safe, though, having a self-calling app is the "known good" method.

sandbox_proc includes a great many static libs, but they appear to mostly be for the sample UI they've built. The only ones I've found that seem to be required for a minimal sandbox are:

```
sandbox.lib base.lib dbghelp.lib
```

There's another dependancy that's not entirely obvious from looking at the project though, and it's what I got caught up on the longest. When you built the sandbox solution, one of the output files should be a "`wowhelper.exe`". Though it's never mentioned anywhere, this file must be copied to the same directory as the executable you are sandboxing! If it's not, your attempts to sandbox your code will always fail with a generic "file not found" error. This can be very frustrating if you don't know what's going on! Now, I'm developing on Windows 7 64bit, which may have something to do with the wowhelper requirement (WOW is a common acronym for interop apps between 16/32/64bit), but I don't have a good way of testing that right now. Please let me know if anyone else finds out more!

So that's all the environment stuff, here's a bit of smaple code to get you going! Please note that although I use wcout in the child process here, you can't see any console output when running in the sandbox. Anything like that needs to be communicated to the parent process via IPC.

```
#include <sandbox/src/sandbox.h>
#include <sandbox/src/sandbox_factory.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int RunParent(int argc, wchar_t* argv[], sandbox::BrokerServices* broker_service) {
    if (0 != broker_service->Init()) {
        wcout << L"Failed to initialize the BrokerServices object" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    sandbox::TargetPolicy* policy = broker_service->CreatePolicy();

    // Here's where you set the security level of the sandbox. Doing a "goto definition" on any
    // of these symbols usually gives you a good description of their usage and alternatives.
    policy->SetJobLevel(sandbox::JOB_LOCKDOWN, 0);
    policy->SetTokenLevel(sandbox::USER_RESTRICTED_SAME_ACCESS, sandbox::USER_LOCKDOWN);
    policy->SetAlternateDesktop(true);
    policy->SetDelayedIntegrityLevel(sandbox::INTEGRITY_LEVEL_LOW);

    //Add additional rules here (ie: file access exceptions) like so:
    policy->AddRule(sandbox::TargetPolicy::SUBSYS_FILES, sandbox::TargetPolicy::FILES_ALLOW_ANY, "some/file/path");

    sandbox::ResultCode result = broker_service->SpawnTarget(argv[0], GetCommandLineW(), policy, &pi);

    policy->Release();
    policy = NULL;

    if (sandbox::SBOX_ALL_OK != result) {
        wcout << L"Sandbox failed to launch with the following result: " << result << endl;
        return 2;
    }

    // Just like CreateProcess, you need to close these yourself unless you need to reference them later
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);

    broker_service->WaitForAllTargets();

    return 0;
}

int RunChild(int argc, wchar_t* argv[]) {
    sandbox::TargetServices* target_service = sandbox::SandboxFactory::GetTargetServices();

    if (NULL == target_service) {
        wcout << L"Failed to retrieve target service" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if (sandbox::SBOX_ALL_OK != target_service->Init()) {
        wcout << L"failed to initialize target service" << endl;
        return 2;
    }

    // Do any "unsafe" initialization code here, sandbox isn't active yet

    target_service->LowerToken(); // This locks down the sandbox

    // Any code executed at this point is now sandboxed!

    TryDoingSomethingBad();

    return 0;
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[]) {
    sandbox::BrokerServices* broker_service = sandbox::SandboxFactory::GetBrokerServices();

    // A non-NULL broker_service means that we are not running the the sandbox, 
    // and are therefore the parent process
    if(NULL != broker_service) {
        return RunParent(argc, argv, broker_service);
    } else {
        return RunChild(argc, argv);
    }
}
```

Hopefully that's enough to get any other curious coders sandboxing! Good luck!

Comment: After looking through resources about chrome's sandbox library for hours, this is the only thing that I've actually found useful. Thank you so much for taking the time to share this!

Comment: I had the same experience before writing this up several years back. I hope it's still relevant!

Comment: I'm looking for something similar to this myself and this certainly seems like the only decent information on the subject and I'm sure you experienced the same thing, but I have looked at literally a few hundred web pages regarding this. I'll give this a shot, many thanks for the help and the time taken to write this

Comment: A couple of other caveats that folks might want to know, from [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/DPzZ3S3Yhsk):
"The sandbox library ... has to reside in the main executable, not in a DLL";
"It should be possible to use a different image for the target, and in that case SANDBOX_EXPORTS should be defined at the project level".
Basically what you've done here is the happy path (using the same executable as both the broker and target).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure precisely what sort of answer you want...
The first thing you should do is check the Chrome Source Code [reference](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/getting-around-the-chrome-source-code).
What interests us is this:

> sandbox: The sandbox project which tries to prevent a hacked renderer from modifying the system.

Spelunking around that code, and looking for API references in the Rendering part of the Chromium could help.

> renderer: Code for the subprocess in each tab. This embeds WebKit and talks to browser for I/O.

Go look around there, you can probably see how Google themselves are using their sandbox, I expect it's going to be something similar to

```
//Lets start up the sandbox, I'm using the Chrome Blog example
TargetPolicy::SetTokenLevel()
TargetPolicy::SetJobLevel()
TargetPolicy::SetIntegrityLevel()
TargetPolicy::SetDesktop()
```

Generally this is the approach I use when meeting a new code base, check how it gets called.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Although it's essentially what I was doing anyway at the time I asked the question, it's certainly good advice for anyone in a similar situation.

Comment: There really isn't another answer, unless your idea of "learning how to use something" is to read the entire source from a to z. Which is...not a good idea.

Comment: Typically you have the luxury of looking at a sample program and being able to cross reference that with API documentation, though. Here the code samples are slim and the documentation non-existent. I've worked with worse, but it's a little disheartening that there is so little in the way of formal reference material in this case. I was mostly wondering if I was overlooking any.