# Dynamic source code shows in browser on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, windows-7, cgi

I'm running Windows 7, and using Google Chrome as my web browser.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print 'content-type: text/html\n'

print """
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title> sample </title>
    </head>

    <body>
"""

print 2 + 3

print """
    </body>
  </html>
"""
```

In Command Prompt, `where python` results in `C:\Python27\python.exe`, but according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take)  I should use `#!/usr/bin/env python` instead.

When I try to run this `.py` code in my browser, the source code appears instead of just `5`.

If someone would provide detailed instructions as to how to properly work this, I would be most grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: Your browser cannot run Python. You need to run this on the server to generate the HTML that will be sent to the browser.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409138/is-it-possible-to-run-native-python-code-in-chrome

Comment: @user2357112 How would I do this?

Comment: @user2357112 I am just trying to run a code from a file on my computer. I don't have a website/server.

Comment: You will need to run a webserver, then. This can be on the same computer.

Comment: @user2357112 That's a little vague. Can you provide step-by-step instructions on how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So of course it is not possible to run python directly in the browser but you can configure a local server to be able to run CGI scripts. Since you are on windows you could use something like a WAMP.
Try following this tutorial
https://wiki.python.org/moin/CgiScripts