# How to build chromium's sandbox only?

Tags: build, chromium, sandbox

How can I use the chromium's sandbox as static lib? And I want to build its sandbox only instead of the whole browser to learn how sandbox works. Any help?

I learned this blog, but seems out of time.
[Using the Google Chrome Sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590337/using-the-google-chrome-sandbox)

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning about Chromium sandboxing too at the moment

I was able to build it as a static library with VS following chromium documentation:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/windows_build_instructions.md

You just need to choose sandbox.vcxproj in solution explorer and build it